# Twitter Restful API throw 401 unauthorized Error while passing count parameter in Query string

Tags: twitter

I am facing 401 unauthorized error when passing count parameter as query string and my getting response in Postman tool successfully. Please specify what i missed in my code

```
string str2 = "q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(stringToEscape5);
string str3 = "&tweet_mode=extended";
string str4 = "&count=100";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(stringToEscape10 + "?" + str2 + str3 + str4);
```

Return number of tweets specified in count parameter.

Comment: Need urgent help on this issue.

Comment: Can you compare the headers that postman generates with your authentication? Also, you should include more code to help understand how you are making the full request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, got solution of this issue. Need to pass bearer access token as post request first so that it will resolve authentication error.